# Sharepoint 2007 : How to set column level permission?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I would like to set the column level permission on list in Sharepoint 2007. I would appreciate help.

Example:

I would like to employee to fill other information in the form but not allow them to change the salary. Only admin can change certain fields.

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456251/sharepoint-2007-how-to-restrict-access-at-the-field-level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that.

SharePoint does not support column level security.

You would need to extend SharePoint to achieve this...

Take a look here.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SecureField

Comment: Glad I didn't explain my "here's how I would do it" approach - the link works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, there are no Column level premissions for SharePoint. However, a nice an easy workaround that I use all the time for this scenario is to create Custom List Forms and use the "display" option for the column to do not want users to edit.  You then create an Edit form where the fields are editable for those that are authorized to edit the entry.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, but I don't believe you have the ability to control permissions on individual columns in SharePoint 2007.  At least I haven't heard of it.  I browsed through list definitions and permissions but I didn't spot anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another 3rd party tool is Sharepoint Column Protector by Datapolis. More details on the tool is discussed here ([How to apply item level permission for sharepoint columns](http://www.wareprise.com/2010/06/14/how-to-apply-item-level-permission-for-sharepoint-columns/)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common request for many SharePoint users, but MS does not provide. You can try 3rd party tools, such as [BoostSolutions Column/View Permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html) and …